# Numbers: Dividing a column by a fixed reference cell in anther sheet in a multi-sheet spreadsheet

Tags: ipad, numbers

I have a spreadsheet that has multiple sheets inside it.
Lets say we have sheet `A` and `B`, I want to divide a column in sheet `A` by a cell in the sheet `B`.

- *I know how it’s done in a single sheet.*
- *I’m using an iPad*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an **iPad**, however, on a **Mac**, settings the *formula* in, e.g., a *cell* in **Table 1** on **Sheet 1**, referencing from **Sheet 2**, it would be, e.g,:

```
=B2/Sheet 2::Table 1::C2
```

Note that if you want to preserve the *row* and *column* reference use, e.g.:

```
=B2/Sheet 2::Table 1::$C$2
```

Obviously changing the *cell*, *sheet* and *table* references as appropriate.

[image]

Note that when the *formula* window is open, one can click on a *cell* in a different *sheet* to add its reference to the *formula*. One can then click on the *down arrow* to click either **Preserve Row** or **Preserve Column**.

[image]